# Tikz externalize sub-folders

Tags: tikz-external

I am currently externalizing my tikz figures in a separate folder using

`\tikzexternalize[prefix=My_folder/]`

I would like to externalize the figures in several sub-folders within `My_folder`. How can I set sub-folders?

Comment: How to determine which figure is stored in which sub-folder?

Comment: I want to change the sub-folder manually at various points of the .tex file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\tikzsetexternalprefix{<file name prefix>}` in the middle of document, and it can be used multiple times.

It is documented in `pgfmanual` v3.1.8, sec. 52.4.2 *Customizing the Generated File Names*.